# New to Developing SharePoint Web Parts and Features

Tags: development, web-part, sharepoint-foundation, error, feature-activation

I recently Developed a really simple web part scoped to site (or at least it's feature is). I also created a feature that up[on activation is suppose to create a new content type.

That's fine and dandy, accept when I deploy the solution to my **Dev** environment I get the following screen, **after** going to `Settings -> Manage Site Features -> Activate Feature Name`

[image]

Now the screen seems pretty simple, I managed to find where the webconfig file was and I did change its already `<customErrors mode="Off" />` to  `<customErrors mode="Off" />`

What I don't understand is:

- How do I create a page that displays errors instead of me seeing this page?
- Where would this page that I create, according to the image, live? Would my web part create a new layout?

I am a complete newb when it comes to SharePoint development and its error pages it throws. I have to learn on the job so I am turning to the community for help on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty way of setting this up:

http://navdeep19.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/sharepoint-2010-how-to-create-custom-error-page-for-sharepoint-website/

I'm not the biggest fan of dumping stuff directly into the 14 hive (I would wrap an application page up in a solution instead) but that at least should give you the Powershell to get started. And if you wanted to customize error pages for different HTTP responses, here's a decent guide to how to do that:

http://www.ngpixel.com/2010/12/23/sharepoint-2010-custom-error-pages/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SharePoint application page is throwing the exception so you need to enable `<customErrors mode="Off" />` for application pages to read the full error message. You can fairly easily enable the full errors by manipulating `web.config` located in `12/14/15` hive layouts folder i.e. `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS`

You can even set your own Custom Error pages as depicted in the [following blog](http://falakmahmood.blogspot.se/2011/11/setting-up-custom-404-access-denied.html#.UbXeX0CnB1E)

Answer (score 0):

There's more than just one config file for SharePoint sites. It'll need changing in all.